# How to deploy private organization image from docker hub to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerhub

#### Current Situation

I have a Kubernetes cluster created on DigitalOcean. I want to deploy a Docker image that is hosted in a private that in turn belongs to an organization in Docker Hub.

- Docker Hub organization name (sample): myorg
- Docker Hub repository name (sample): myorg/mo-server

So in order to push a new image I use `docker push myorg/mo-server`

(Note: The example above contains a dash (`-`) in the name of the image which I have in the real name as well)

#### Problem

When I try to deploy that docker image to kubernetes using `kubectl` the deployment always ends up in status `ErrImagePull`. Error message:

```
ailed to pull image "index.docker.io/myorg/mo-server": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myorg/mo-server, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

#### What I tried so far

Because it is a private repository I'm creating a secret beforehand. For this, I'm using the username and E-Mail of myself.

```
set DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER=https://index.docker.io/v1/
set DOCKER_USER=sarensw
set DOCKER_EMAIL=stephan@myorg.com
set DOCKER_PASSWORD=...
```

The credentials are the same as when I use `docker login`. Then I create a secret using:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred 
  --docker-server=%DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER% 
  --docker-username=%DOCKER_USER% 
  --docker-password=%DOCKER_PASSWORD% 
  --docker-email=%DOCKER_EMAIL%
```

Then, I use `kubectl create` to create a new deployment.

```
kubectl create -f ci\helper\kub-deploy-staging.yaml
```

`kub-deploy-staging.yaml` looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mo-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mo-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mo-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mo-server
          image: index.docker.io/myorg/mo-server
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: [ "echo", "SUCCESS" ]
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

The result is `ErrImagePull` as described above.

I'm pretty sure that the `image: index.docker.io/myorg/mo-server` is the culprit because it is an organization image that I try to use with a normal account. And all the tutorials for accessing a private image do not take organizations into account.

So what am I doing wrong?

*(one of many similar) references:* https://gist.github.com/rkuzsma/b9a0e342c56479f5e58d654b1341f01e

Comment: No tags on your image?

Comment: I have. I tried with and without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this happens because of the docker registry variable with which you have created your secret, please try substituting `index.docker.io` with `registry.hub.docker.com` as this is the official dockerhub registry URL. If you are using Google cloud you can also try `docker.io`

Comment: That's it. I had to use `registry.hub.docker.com`. Took me so long. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are trying to set your variable with "set" command, and please try now with "export" as in mentioned in [gist](https://gist.github.com/rkuzsma/b9a0e342c56479f5e58d654b1341f01e) file that you follow

```
export DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER=https://index.docker.io/v1/
export DOCKER_USER=Type your dockerhub username, same as when you `docker login`
export DOCKER_EMAIL=Type your dockerhub email, same as when you `docker login`
export DOCKER_PASSWORD=Type your dockerhub pw, same as when you `docker login`

kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey \
  --docker-server=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER \
  --docker-username=$DOCKER_USER \
  --docker-password=$DOCKER_PASSWORD \
  --docker-email=$DOCKER_EMAIL
```

Then try again and let us know the result please.

Comment: I'm on Windows, therefore I use set instead of export. This is not a problem. I can see that the secret is successfully created. And I also did it without the system variables. No luck.

Comment: Ok, then I guess it should work just fine if your user has write access to this organizational repo. And I didn't try on Windows, I tried in Linux, at it works just fine